# How to create a plugin to turn a cordova phonegap into a launcher

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to turn my cordova app into a launcher for **reasons** including limiting access to other apps, and help users well, focus on my app and preventing them from accidentaly closing it.

I tried lots of things but after reading the docs adding this to plugin.xml was my latest attempt.

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:name='MainActivity']" mode="merge">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </activity>
 </edit-config>
```

But i ended up getting this error when adding it...

> Warning: Failed to install 'custom-plugin-id':TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'length' of undefined

**Where am i doing wrong?**

Comment: Have you got solution for this?

Comment: Yes I have.. You must also by now